# how to resume ffmpeg streamer for network disconnection for a period of time but eventually recovery

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

I can stream my video well by using ffmpeg's libav* when network is good，but I can not guarantee that the network will always be good.I hope that when the network is bad, even disconnect for a period of time, the streaming process can resume and continue to stream video when network recover. I have tried, when I was streaming the video, I manually disconnected the network, the streamer stopped quickly. After 20 seconds, I resumed the network, the process resumed to stream as well in a few seconds.But if I disconnect the network for five minutes or longer, when the network is restored, the process blocked.Dose someone knows how to resume the streamer instread of blocking no matter how long the network is disconnected but eventually recovered（not by restarting the program）.Could you give me some solution if you know ，thanks .

I have googled the solution,but can't find something useful.So I come here to ask for help

```
static int encode_and_write_frame(AVCodecContext *codec_ctx, AVFormatContext *fmt_ctx, AVFrame *frame)
{
    AVPacket pkt = {0};
    av_init_packet(&pkt);
    int ret = avcodec_send_frame(codec_ctx, frame);
    if (ret < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error sending frame to codec context!\n");
        return ret;
    }
    ret = avcodec_receive_packet(codec_ctx, &pkt);
    //pkt.dts = pkt.pts;
    if (ret < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error receiving packet from codec context!\n" );
        return ret;
    }
    av_interleaved_write_frame(fmt_ctx, &pkt);
    av_packet_unref(&pkt);
    return 0;
}


void Streamer::stream_frame(const cv::Mat &image)
{
    if(can_stream()) {
        const int stride[] = {static_cast<int>(image.step[0])};
        sws_scale(scaler.ctx, &image.data, stride, 0, image.rows, picture.frame->data, picture.frame->linesize);
        picture.frame->pts += av_rescale_q(1, out_codec_ctx->time_base, out_stream->time_base);
 //picture.frame->dts = picture.frame->pts;
        encode_and_write_frame(out_codec_ctx, format_ctx, picture.frame);
    }
}


while(ok) {
        process_frame(read_frame, proc_frame);
        if(!from_camera) {
            streamer.stream_frame(proc_frame);
        } else {
            streamer.stream_frame(proc_frame, frame_time.count()*streamer.inv_stream_timebase);
        }
        ok = video_capture.read(read_frame);
        time_prev = time_stop;
    }
```

Comment: Why do you think that ffmpeg has code that deals with network disconnects? BTW: The difference between 20s and 300s may be TCP connection timeouts. In one case, both sides still consider it an intermittent fault and keep the connections alive, so they can just pick up when packets arrive again. The appliation only notices the delay. In the other case, the connection is really closed and the application is notified of the closed connection. That said, as a new user here, please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: I'm late because I've been on vacation recently. Thank you for your answer. First of all, I'm sorry to ask such a question. I thought ffmpeg has good support for the network, but it doesn't. According to your answer, I need to implement the logic of TCP connection at the application level by myself. Could you  tell me that some recommended tools can handle such problems.Thanks @UlrichEckhardt.